# State hoisting in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, state, hoisting

This post has been edited in order to provide more context to my question. The "final" version, which I can develop with my current knowledge and the solution that I can understand better, is this. I would appreciate it if you could analyze it and give me the OK. I am aware that there may be some better solutions, but this one is mine ;)

```
            var myTextQuantityState by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }

            Text(myTextQuantityState)

            Button(
                Modifier.constrainAs(buttonAdd) {
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    bottom.linkTo(buttonOrder.top)
                    top.linkTo(imageIceCream.bottom)
                },
                myTextQuantityState
            )
            { myTextQuantityState = it }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Text(text: Int) {
    Text(
        text = text.toString(),
    )
}

@Composable
fun Button(
    modifier: Modifier,
    currentTextQuantityState: Int,
    increaseIceCreamQuantity: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            increaseIceCreamQuantity(currentTextQuantityState + 1)
        },
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm 2 months into Android so I can't tell you the "best" way. But here is how I would do it.

```
var myTextQuantityState by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }

Text( text = myTextQuantityState.toString() )

Button( onClick = { myTextQuantityState += 1 } ) {}
```

The reason I would do it this way is because I would prefer to have the lambda in a position to directly access the quantity without having to pass it as a variable like you are doing with the `increaseIceCreamQuantity` function

Here is how it would work if the state and button were in different composables

```
@Composable
fun screen1() {
   var myTextQuantityState by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }

   Text( text = myTextQuantityState.toString() )
   screen2(increment = { myTextQuantityState += 1 })
}

@Composable
fun screen2(
   increment: () -> Unit
) {  
   Button( onClick = { increment() } ) {}
}
```

Based on your current code. The solution is still similar to the function I have above. The `currentTextQuantityState` value you have as a parameter in your Button composable is actually a reference to the original one so you can still pass a lambda that doesn't need an input. Here is an edit of your code to clarify what I mean. I have put `...` to skip code I didn't change

```
           ...
            Button(
                Modifier..., 
// A CHANGE HERE. NO NEED TO PASS IN myTextQuantityState. It can be modified from here by the button. The button gets the lambda and the lambda has access to myTextQuantityState. The button in your scenario does not need direct access to myTextQuantityState
                { myTextQuantityState += 1 }, // HERE IS A CHANGE
            )
            ...
}

...

@Composable
fun Button(
    modifier: Modifier, 
    increaseIceCreamQuantity: () -> Unit // HERE IS A CHANGE
) {
    Button(
        onClick = {
            increaseIceCreamQuantity() // HERE IS A CHANGE
        },
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your solution would not work in the specific case I am trying to simulate. The provided code is not showing the complete context; it is only an example. In the correct context, you would not have direct access to the state because, with state hoisting, my button would be in a @Composable function and its state would be in its parent. Therefore, you wouldn't be able to change the state directly as you are doing.

Comment: @LordProfesor Add some more context to help clarify anything you think I might be missing. Meanwhile, I have added an edit with more code to show how I would do it if the state and button were in different composables

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your time. I have made an edit to my original code, and now the question is different. So now I just need an opinion about my code. Is it good code or is it a mess? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LordProfesor check out the edit I made to the answer

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the second implementation currently isn't hoisted, as you have direct access to the stateful value. In terms of what you can do, you *can* (as in it will work) pass the `MutableState<T>` directly, where you have both a getter and setter. This is effectively what the first option does through the use of delegates:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables

```
val (value, setValue) = remember { mutableStateOf(default) }
```

Passing in the value + a setter lambda directly however is compose agnostic, as how you get the value and what you provide in the lambda can be whatever you want.

---

If your goal is to use data down several composables, with the option to modify data, and you'd like to avoid passing a getter and a setter to each composable, you can take a look at `CompositionLocal`:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal#deciding

It allows you to get values within tree hierarchy, at the cost of making it harder to reason about the data you have available. Some parent is expected to provide the `CompositionLocal`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your time. I have made an edit to my original code, and now the question is different. So now I just need an opinion about my code. Is it good code or is it a mess? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Commenting on your code and the other answer, they both hoist the state above Button and are fine. Whether you want a listener that takes in the expected value to set (yours) or a generic one (other solution) is up to you. Odds are you will also want to display something, so passing in the value is also fine. As for your screen, if you intend on placing it elsewhere, you may choose to further hoist the data. You can imagine moving it into a two panel layout for instance, where you may want to use the state outside of just that screen.